# Is it possible to embed (inline) a zip file in an XHTML document?

Tags: xhtml

Images can be embedded inline encoded as base64 in a xhtml document, for example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD
 NCAMAAAAsYgRbAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5c
 cllPAAAABJQTFRF3NSmzMewPxIG//ncJEJsldTou1jHgAAAARBJREFUeNrs2EEK
 gCAQBVDLuv+V20dENbMY831wKz4Y/VHb/5RGQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ
 0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0PzMWtyaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoxtb0QGho
 aGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaMbRLEvv50VTQ9OTQ5OpyZ01GpM2g0bfmDQaL7S+ofFC6x
 v3ZpxJiywakzbvd9r3RWPS9I2+MWk0+kbf0Hih9Y17U0nTHibrDDQ0NDQ0NDQ0
 NDQ0NDQ0NTXbRSL/AK72o6GhoaGhoRlL8951vwsNDQ0NDQ1NDc0WyHtDTEhD
 Q0NDQ0NTS5MdGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGposzSHAAErMwwQ2HwRQ
 AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="beastie.png"/>
```

([source](http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/))

Is it possible to do the same with an arbitrary attachment (for example a zip file) that can be downloaded (clicking a link or a button) and accessed using javascript?

Comment: Yes. In the same way. Have you tried? Did you encounter a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```html
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==" download target="_blank">download</a>
```

`application/octet-stream` is a generic MIME type for binary data, generally forces browsers to download the file.

The file itself is from [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/small/blob/master/zip.zip), though doesn't really work as a zip.

`download` is a more modern way to force download.